# Как написать метод который потоком читает текстовый файл и возвращает список обьектов?

Tags: java, java-stream

Хочу написать метод который читает поток txt файлик, и возвращает из него список объектов ( в моем случае список отелей). Как то правильно сделать?

[image: то что находиться в txtФайлике]

```
private List<Hotel> readHotelBD(String path) throws Exception {
    userRepository.validate(path);
    ArrayList<Hotel> hotelList = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            hotelList.add(line);
        }
    }
    return hotelList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static List<Hotel> readHotelDB(String dbPath) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(dbPath))
            .map(line -> line.substring(line.indexOf("{") + 1, line.indexOf("}")))
            .map(s -> {
                String[] fields = s.split(",");
                int id = Integer.parseInt(fields[0].split("=")[1]);
                String name = fields[1].split("=")[1].replace("'", "");
                String country = fields[2].split("=")[1].replace("'", "");
                String city = fields[3].split("=")[1].replace("'", "");
                String street = fields[4].split("=")[1].replace("'", "");
                return new Hotel(id, name, country, city, street);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще то это не текстовый файл, а файл в формате JSon, причем судя по всему 1 строчка 1 json объект (что не очень обычно).

Вам надо прочитать 1 строчку и распарсить Json в Java объект.

Как парсить Json объекты - поищите поиском, здесь тонны примеров и ответов.

Comment: а есть вариант без json?

Comment: Можно и поизвращаться )))

Comment: больше всего похоже на записанные объекты из метода toString